# Regarding reapplying for the Schengen visa in Estonia

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, estonia

My question is - right now I'm visiting my fiancée in Estonia. I got a visa in India - just the single entry Schengen visa which is valid till the 20th of August 2013.  I am leaving Estonia on 17th of Aug 2013 and joining a ship for work in Denmark.  My fiancée is pregnant and the baby is supposed to be born at the end of October. Being in Estonia, can I reapply for the Schengen visa or not, so that I can come back in October when my baby is due to be born?

Comment: @atzal I've edited your question, as you really need to write these carefully - grammar and punctuation is incredibly important, even if it's not your first language.  I think I've made it make more sense, and have kept the message - let us know if  there is a mistake, or edit it yourself.  I also assume you have an Indian passport?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question I was referring to in my post in the Meta section.

Comment: I doubt if you can reapply for visa in Estonia, if you do not have local resident permit. Trying via business visa might help though.

Comment: With a pregnant fiancée living there you may struggle to get a tourist visa, as they'll be worried you'll stay there and not leave at the end. Can you not apply for something like a marriage visa that would entitle you to remain?